# How to prompt user for register name?

Tags: interactive, registers

I'd like to prompt the user for a register name. Is there an easy way to do this? Apparently, this functionality isn't built into `interactive` (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html)...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just by looking at source code of the first function I found via apropos that has anything to do with registers, I found `register-read-with-preview`. It might be what you're looking for.

You can prompt for registers only when calling a function interactively by passing code that returns a list of arguments to `interactive` as it's argument.

Here's the docstring:

> register-read-with-preview is a compiled Lisp function in ‘register.el’.
>
> (register-read-with-preview PROMPT)
>
> Read and return a register name, possibly showing existing registers.
> Prompt with the string PROMPT.  If ‘register-alist’ and
> ‘register-preview-delay’ are both non-nil, display a window
> listing existing registers after ‘register-preview-delay’ seconds.
> If ‘help-char’ (or a member of ‘help-event-list’) is pressed,
> display such a window regardless.

Comment: That works, thanks! I didn't think to check the source code.